# Package babel Error: No Cyrillic encoding definition files were found

Tags: cyrillic

On Ubuntu using TeXworks, I get this error when building a document containing Ukrainian characters. Works fine on Windows with MiKTeX. How to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `texlive-lang-cyrillic`:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-cyrillic
```

Source: http://www.linux.org.ru/forum/general/3533588#comment-3533849